# CoreData & RestKit - Fetching same entity type from multiple sources

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm accessing an API using the latest version of RestKit, and am pulling down some "Event" objects.

I have two different API endpoints:
1. "All Events"
2. "This user's events"

The Events from endpoint #2 are a subset of those from endpoint #1.

At the moment, I've created two different CoreData entities, one for each endpoint. This works, but is inefficient - there's duplication of those events that are in the subset.

What I'd like to do is use endpoint #1 to pull down all the events, and then use endpoint #2 to flag those events (from endpoint #1) that relate to this user.

Is it possible to use RKEntityMapping to map an arbitrary value (flag) into received objects - I could therefore flag the user's events as they arrive, but still put them into the same CoreData entities as the superset of events.

Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, what you propose is the only way this should be done. I do not know about RestKit, but you can simply first fetch the user's events, insert into Core Data, and then fetch all events and only insert those that are not contained in the user events. If you have two arrays of dictionaries or managed objects a simple predicate would do:

```
NSArray *userEventIDs = [userEvents valueForKeyPath:@"idNumber"];
NSSet *newEvents = [allEvents filteredSetUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not (idNumber in %@)", userEventIDs]];
```

Comment: So, how should I flag the user's events as they are received? Without that, with what you're proposing, wouldn't I still end up with one whole set of all of the events with no way of identifying those relating to the user.

Comment: You stated that you are using Core Data. Surely, your object model would include a one-to-many relationship from User to Events. Right?

Comment: you're absolutely right of course! I guess that I was just blinded by the apparent simplicity of RestKit and mimicking the remote data structures whereas I should just create the relationship in my local DB (or CoreData) myself. Thanks for your help.